# jQuery function executed on load when passing a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to figure out how to pass variables to jQuery functions, but I'm at a loss why this (greatly simplified) example doesn't work as intended. The idea is that an alert will be shown when the checkbox is clicked.

No problem here:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check"/>

<script>

  do_alert = function() {
    alert("Welcome");
  }

  $('.check').change(do_alert);

</script>
```

However, when passing the alert text to the function, the alert is shown as soon as the page loads, with the correct message text:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check"/>

<script>

  do_alert = function(message) {
    alert(message);
  }

  $('.check').change(do_alert("Welcome"));

</script>
```

As does this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check"/>

<script>

  function do_alert(message) {
    alert(message);
  }

  $('.check').change(do_alert("Welcome"));

</script>
```

In both cases, the function isn't executed when checking the box, but it is on loading the page. What am I missing here?

Comment: `change` expects a function as an argument, but by using `do_alert("Welcome")` you're invoking the function and only passing its `undefined` results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `$('.check').change(do_alert);` works is because you are passing a reference to the `do_alert` function to the `change` event handler, and that event handler executes `do_alert()` when needed. The reason why `$('.check').change(do_alert("Welcome"));` does not work is because you are executing the `do_alert` function instead of passing it as a reference in that case. In order to pass parameters, you would need to wrap your function call in an anonymous function, like so:

```
$('.check').change(function(){
    do_alert("Welcome");
});
```

What happens there is that you are creating an anonymous function (`function() { ... }`), but you are not executing it (because there are no parentheses after the function definition). So you are passing a reference to your anonymous function, which is what your event handler expects.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  do_alert = function(param) {
    alert(param);
  }  
    $('.check').change(function() {
       do_alert("Welcome");  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check"/>
```